# Weird Script Performance in Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, animation

I have a website with a JavaScript function that loops through images for an animation (Arbitrary Turtle logo). http://arbitraryturtle.github.io/

On Chrome it looks as intended, same with Microsoft Edge, but on Firefox it looks very jittery with the images in the animation only partially loading.

My animation function:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
    var anim;
    var index = 0;
    function Animation () {
        anim = setInterval(DoAnimation, 125);
    }
    function DoAnimation () {
        document.getElementById('anim').src = "media/Animation/" + index.toString() + ".png";
        index++;
        if (index == 19) {
            clearInterval(anim);
        }
    }
    window.onload = Fixes;
</script>
```

**Edit** Noticed that Firefox gives an "Image corrupt or truncated" error

Comment: check the console - you have errors

Comment: Thanks, but its unrelated and I get the error in Chrome and Firefox. **Edit** I fixed the irrelevant error. Only in Firefox I get a image corrupt/truncate error for some reason.

Comment: first make a function to load all your images, then, start the animation.

Comment: This seems to be an ongoing issue with Firefox. http://tinyurl.com/oj62xo6

Comment: Thanks Kaiido that really helped with all browsers/platforms! Thank you to Shikkediel as well for pointing out the known bug